# how to set up a job to have two run windows? Please see sample job below.

Tags: autosys

How can I set up a Autosys job to run at two separate intervals? Please see the sample job below.

This job needs to run between 00:06 - 00:56 and then again between 04:06 - 04:56. The start_mins can be same.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Your example requires two jobs. One with run_window: 00:06 - 00:56 and the second with run_window:  04:06 - 04:56.

> Syntax This attribute has the following format: run_window:
>   "time-time" time-time Defines the interval during which a job may
>   start in the format "hh:mm-hh:mm", where hh denotes hours (in 24-hour
>   format) and mm denotes minutes. You must enclose the interval in
>   quotation marks (") and separate the beginning and ending times with a
>   hyphen (-). The specified interval can overlap midnight, but cannot
>   encompass more than 24 hours. Limits: Up to 20 alphanumeric characters

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the Job exactly once between 00:06 - 00:56 and 04:06 - 04:56 time frames you can try to set starttime as 00.06 and 04.06 and set 
max_run_alarm: 50

Answer (score 0):

Use a Notrunning Condition:

Update_job: YourStartMinsJob
condition: notrunning(ExclusionJob)

insert_job: ExclusionJob
date_conditions: 1 days_of_week: all start_times: "00:56"
command: sleep 11400 #3h10m in secs

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).